# Refreshing display objects after resizing

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an app that contains a CControlBar and in that sits a few CStatic Objects which each display an icon with some text.

I have a bug where if I keep resizing the control bar a bit using the mouse, all the text and icons on the control bat as well as other icons and menu item texts across my whole app go invisible / break.

Is there a specific type of redraw function of a specific class that i should be using from the onSize method? or is there something else i need to be doing?

Thanks

Comment: (You should mention that you are using MFC to get better answers)

Comment: Check the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style on the control bar, and add or remove it depending on whether you already have it or not. I've noticed several bugs relating to that in Windows/MFC. Alternatively, since you say that other items elsewhere in your app also break, check if you aren't leaking GDI handles somewhere and are running out.